# CMake and issues with header files in subfolders

Tags: c, cmake

I'm trying to set up a project where header files can be found by the subfolder libraries src code as well as the src code in the top level using Cmake. Currently i am getting an error stating that the header file can not be found. The structure of my project looks like this:

```
root/
    src/           
        CMakeLists.txt     #(top level)  
        main.c     
        lib/
            lib1.c
            CMakeLists.txt     #(lower level)
            headers/
                lib1.h
    build/
```

My top level CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4)

project(CmakeTUT_Proj) 

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.c)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Lib/headers/)
                                                          
add_subdirectory(Lib/)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Lib/headers/)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} name_of_lib)
```

My lower level CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
add_library(name_of_lib  adder.c)
```

My main.c and my lib1.c programs include the library as `#include "lib1.h"`, cmake runs fine without any errors but when i build the project with `make` i get an error like:

```
root/src/Lib/lib1.c:2:10: fatal error: lib1.h: No such file or directory
#include "lib1.h"
```

I want to structure my project so that main.c and lib1.c have access to lib1.h. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Think about `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Lib/)`... Is the header file really in `Lib`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my bad, that was a typo, it still does not work like this

Comment: I've taken the liberty to edit the description of your project structure to make it hopefully easier to understand.

Comment: `add_library(name_of_lib` - there is no `name_of_lib` library. `target_link_directories` is missing a `)`. Did you add the `headers` directory into the search paths when compiling `lib1.c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name implies, `target_include_directories` only affects one target. So when you set `target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Lib/headers/)`, this adds to the include path for the executable target named `${PROJECT_NAME}` but not to the include path for the library `name_of_lib`.

To fix this, you can add the include path for your library in the lower level `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_include_directories(name_of_lib PUBLIC headers)
```

As a bonus, because it's `PUBLIC`, this path is also automatically added to any target that depends on `name_of_lib`. So in the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`, you can remove this line:

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Lib/headers/)
```

---

Aside, this line looks useless and can probably be removed as well:

```
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Lib/headers/)
```

Link libraries are not usually placed in headers directories.